# flash drive is not visible for mount and fdisk

Tags: mount, usb-drive, dmesg, lsusb

I was installing ubuntu studio on asus laptop and something went wrong during installation.
I mean I corrupted my installation medium (silicon power flash drive, 16gb) somehow.
then I used lsblk and it was named as `/sdb` with partition `/sdb1` on it. I used `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb` to clear the device.
now it is not shown in neither gparted nor disks utility. and I cannot mount that one for sure.

Here is some output from other tools:

```
amelancier@amelanchier:~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b071 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 2.0M UVC Webcam / CNF7129
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub


amelancier@amelanchier:~$ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   215G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0  17.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
amelancier@amelanchier:~$*
```

I cannot put output of dmesg here because cannot format question properly but it tells something similar to lsusb, I mean the device is present.
and in addition there was a moment when both `/dev/disk/by-id/` and `/dev/disk/by-path/` had shown the device as broken link being titling it as `/sdb` in 'properties' in thunar.

I have read many posts on ubuntu-related pages but neither had provided me with a solution.
Mostly they depicted cases when a card was been mounted or at least shown in gparted, lsblk, fdisk etc.
I have two asus laptops but working one is of ten years already and its dvd drive cannot write an installation media to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have performed several forced shutdowns as i can remember now; maybe i have removed it before the prompt but i am not sure.

i guess that after corrupting the drive i have erased its header (or something called in that manner) with dd beyond the repair.
only after doing that i have read about all the danger from using `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb`.
no one could ever provide a solution for such erasure in the posts i had read then.

but i have another [smaller] flash drive that had become unreadable [exactly like one mentioned in the question] after i had performed a backup of my collection of images and photos and various other small files.
maybe that is USB port`s failure --using external drives and audio cards with both of my laptops i have encountered a lot of troubles with USB Type A [2.0, 3.0]...

i use tiny lancet to adjust port`s contacts... that helps temporarily; i have refused to swap Type A [2.0] ports for Type B [2.0] (that was my own idea --my two guitar processors have very reliable Type B ports).
that would be A REALLY BAD MOD!!!

Comment: Sorry I am not seeing this as an answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try Gnome Disks.

Search for Disks under Activity.  Generally, it can help you work with volumes even when not mounted.

Used in concert with lsblk should get you more details on what the actual format is, and then you may need to install additional tools to work with that format.

For example, if it's NTFS or ExFat formats, you might need to run

```
     sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

to work with that type of format in your flash drive.

Good luck,
mondotofu